# What are these targets in node for?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, node-modules

I have the following in my package json that is responsible for building and running the Angular 2 application. May I know the meaning of each of the flags in the targets ? This for deploying an Angular 2 application in IBM Bluemix

```
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your questions are located in the documentation for each of the node js libraries:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

The `build` script is deleting the `dist` folder, then building your app with webpack.

The `start` script is compiling your typescript and then running the typescript compiler in watch mode and then starting `lite-server` concurrently.

Comment: Thanks that helps out a lot!